# ¿Qué es una "bala de plata"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

Leyendo el artículo [Epidemia de terror urbano](http://internacional.elpais.com/internacional/2016/11/30/actualidad/1480504948_770791.html) sobre la inseguridad y criminalidad en ciudades de América Latina en el periódico español El País, así como la dificultad de atajarlo. En él me topé con el siguiente fragmento:

> La solución requerirá tiempo. A su alrededor se acumulan grandes palabras: educación, redistribución, enfoques integrales. “**No hay bala de plata** y depende de si los países tienen una tasa alta o baja de criminalidad, pero desde luego la inversión social y reducir la impunidad ayudan”, indica el profesor Marcelo Bergman. “Hay que cuidarse del populismo penal, la mano dura y la tolerancia cero. Quien promete remedios a corto plazo no es creíble. Pero tampoco hay que resignarse: el esfuerzo social colectivo puede lograr resultados drásticos en 5 o 10 años”, explica Schedler.

Como veis, destaco la expresión *bala de plata*, pues es la que me sorprendió. Su significado parece claro: remedio infalible, solución definitiva. Sin embargo, nunca la había oído mencionar y me encuentro con que la Wikipedia recoge en un [artículo homónimo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bala_de_plata):

> Según algunas leyendas, cuentos y tradiciones, una bala de plata es el único tipo de munición para un arma de fuego que resultaría efectiva para matar a hombres lobo y vampiros, entre otras criaturas fantásticas.

Luego sigue hablando de que a la plata históricamente se la ha considerado poseedora de propiedad místicas, etc.

Por tanto, parece que el artículo usa este significado. Sin embargo, me pregunto: ¿es siempre así? ¿tiene siempre esta significación mística/mítica? ¿en qué ámbitos y países se usa?

Comment: Es un dicho la mar de común en inglés, y significa una solución sencilla (en el sentido funcionar por sí sola), rápida y eficaz.

Comment: If i were translating it into English I would use magic bullet but that may be because that is more familiar in the medical field.

Comment: @mdewey interestingly, I discovered about [bite the bullet](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/247999/37429) in this site, so I am discovering many things about bullets in here :)

Comment: @guifa De hecho, no creo que sea una expresión española, sino un préstamo del inglés traducido literalmente. [Aquí](http://www.werewolves.com/deadly-silver-and-full-moons/), además, hay alguien que sostiene que la idea de que las balas de plata matan hombres lobo se originó recientemente, y en el cine.

Comment: mmm....las balas de plata matan hombres lobo pero no vampiros. Esos necesitan estaca de madera o luz del sol. Decapitarlos también parece funcionar. Te va a tocar ver la saga [Underworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320691/)...es muy entretenida. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El origen de esta expresión es de su equivalente en Inglés "*There is [no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)*", la cual se utiliza mucho en el campo de la Ingeniería en Sistemas. Su popularidad se debe a un [artículo](http://worrydream.com/refs/Brooks-NoSilverBullet.pdf) escrito por [Fred Brooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Brooks) en 1986, el cual se ha discutido a menudo en el área de Sistemas.

El artículo en cuestión utiliza el término "silver bullet" (bala de plata) frecuentemente, una de las frases más relevantes para entender la expresión se encuentra en el [artículo mencionado anteriormente](http://worrydream.com/refs/Brooks-NoSilverBullet.pdf):

> Nevertheless, Ada will not prove to be the **silver bullet** *that slays the software productivity monster*.

la cual se traduce como:

> Sin embargo, (el lenguaje de progamación) Ada no será la **bala de plata** *que elimine al monstruo de la productividad del desarrollo de software*.

Esta frase permite ver la analogía más claramente: Brooks compara el problema de productividad en el área del desarrollo de software con una criatura mística a la que se puede eliminar con una bala de plata y se dedica a explicar por qué tal bala de plata no existe.

En la comunidad de desarrollo de software, la frase "*There is no silver bullet*" es un recordatorio, una advertencia, que no existe una solución mágica (ni única) que funcione en todas las situaciones contra un problema que se percibe como místico (Es decir, que no se le ha encontrado o buscado razones específicas). También sirve para invitar al análisis de un problema para desmistificarlo y así encontrarle una solución racional.

Dicho esto, la acepción de bala de plata en Inglés es

> 1. Un medio infalible de ataque o defensa.
> 2. Un simple remedio para un problema difícil u obstinado.

La razón detrás de la plata en particular es no solamente por el mito de los licántropos sino porque existe la creencia (errónea) que la mayoría de las criaturas sobrenaturales son vulnerables a la plata. Algunas obras de ficción orientales y occidentales hacen mención de la plata siendo el único metal que afecta tanto a vampiros y hombres lobro, lo cual lleva a los protagonistas a recurrir a armas de plata.

Así bien, se perciben las pistolas como las armas más versátiles para la caza y protección (siendo que en los Estados Unidos es popular el obtener armas para ambos propósitos). Por lo tanto, una bala de plata (en teoría) brindaría la mayor versatilidad y efectividad posible para enfrentar a las fuerzas sobrenaturales.

En cuanto a la cuestión de por qué un Mexicano usaría el término "bala de plata" en lugar de "panacea" es debido a la cercanía cultural con los Estados Unidos. En mi caso en particular, la primera vez que escuché la frase en una discusión de informática tomé nota de ella y me he visto tentado a usarla cuando hablo en español, a pesar de que mi primera impresión fue "ah, es el equivalente de la panacea".

Finalmente, la diferencia intrínsica entre una bala de plata y la panacea es el enfoque que se le da: La panacea es para **curar o remediar** cualquier mal, la bala de plata es para **eliminar** cualquier criatura mística. Otra diferencia siendo que la panacea no existe, mientras que una bala de plata se puede manufacturar para todos aquellos que crean en lo sobrenatural (o los ingenieros que se burlan de otros, regalando balas de plata a los ingenuos).

Comment: Muy interesante, buen análisis del tema. Voy a puntualizarte una cosa, cuando dices "...debido a la cercanía cultural con los Americanos" refiriéndote a los estadounidenses, y con mayúsculas además, parece que los mexicanos no fueran americanos también. Reconozco que yo también cometo ese error a menudo pero intento corregirlo.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, igual que todo lo que estás publicando recientemente. ¡Bienvenidísimo a [spanish.se]!

Comment: Casualmente acabo de encontrar la expresión en una publicación de [meta.se]: [Place answers into demilitarized zone instead of 5 minute grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230715/209901): _Too many people look at games - or especially "gamification" - as a silver bullet that will turn the efforts of lazy and unproductive players into gold... This is exceedingly naive. Any game played in bad faith will have disappointing results, whether the mechanics of that game involves throwing a ball around or answering programming questions._

Comment: @blonfu Mi intención no era el expresar que los Mexicanos no son Americanos. A pesar de que el término "*Norteamericanos*" también se utiliza para referir a los Estadounidenses también se podría prestar a la misma interpretación, ya que los Mexicanos también pertenecen a Norte América. Yo también solía corregir a los Estadounidenses acerca del término pero debo confesar que tras años de escuchar "*Americans*", "*Americans*", uno termina por llarmarlos por como ellos se denominan. Así como el uso de "*bala de plata*", el uso de "*Americanos*" es causado por "*cercanía cultural*".

Comment: @fedorqui Muchisimas gracias por la bienvenida y los cumplidos. Es curioso como una de mis respuestas con menos puntuación es aquella que me brinda la más cálida recepción. También es cómico ver que encontraras la expresión en un área relevante a lo que describía.

Comment: @Jorge, lo entiendo perfectamente, de todas formas que los estadounidenses se llamen a si mismos americanos está bien porque lo son pero en una frase que hay otras naciones o pueblos de América me parece injusto que los americanos sean los estadounidenses y el resto quede fuera. Yo lo veo desde el otro lado del charco y quizá desde allí se entienda de otra manera, no lo sé. Definimos cosas con palabras pero las palabras acaban definiendo las cosas a su vez  y cambia la forma en que percibimos el mundo, por eso me parece importante el sentido que le damos a algunas palabras.

Comment: @blonfu Edité la respuesta para eliminar el uso del término "Americanos" ya que no tengo apego alguno a él. A pesar de que comprendo y abogo lo que dices, la cuestión de los Estadounidenses refiriéndose a ellos mismos como "Americanos" es cultural y por las características de su lenguaje. El Inglés es práctico y corto, para ellos un término como "United States American" es algo engorroso, incluso el llamar a su país "United States of America" es reducido a "America" por razones prácticas. Yo comparto tu punto de vista pero también tengo que verlo desde su perspectiva.

Comment: @blonfu Además, el nombre oficial de México es "Estados Unidos Mexicanos" pero es más aceptable para los Mexicanos el que acortemos nuestra denominación mientras que no encontramos aceptable que los Estadounidenses lo hagan. Yendo más allá, incluso el decir "Estadounidense" no es preciso porque hay varios "Estados Unidos". La diferencia obvia siendo que los Estados Unidos de América tienen a "América", el continente, en su nombre y el acortarlo puede causar confusión y malestar.

Answer (score 3):

El misticismo y los hombres lobo se encuentran en el origen de la frase, hoy en día nadie va a usarla con esas connotaciones (siempre hay excepciones, por supuesto, si cuentas el número de flipad... perdón, personas, que crean que existen hombres lobo, seguramente tendrás un número aproximado de las excepciones), simplemente se usará con el significado obvio que tú ya apuntas.

Además, en España no es de uso común, sino más bien poético. Yo desde luego jamás la he oído, solo la he leído y siempre con esa intención de embellecer, o exagerar, para la cual se usan este tipo de frases raras, antiguas o poéticas.
En cuanto a los ámbitos, pues es que realmente no hay ninguno específico, es muy general, parecida a la típica [*panacea*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RcxGdbs), que también tiene un origen místico (un brebaje que cura cualquier mal) y se usa mucho más en el lenguaje hablado y con el mismo significado: **La panacea no existe**; también para exagerar un bien, algo bueno: **esto es la panacea**. Ninguna de estas frases tiene un ámbito específico, se pueden usar casi en cualquier contexto.

Comment: De hecho, ahora veo que [el autor del artículo](https://twitter.com/jmahrens) es corresponsal del periódico en México, Centroamérica y el Caribe. Indagando un poco más veo que es español, por lo que tal vez lo usa en sentido poético pero también... ¿tomando su uso de México?

Comment: A eso no te sabría responder, no sé si se usa más o menos en México comparado con su uso en España, la verdad.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no es tan común la expresión, su uso esta permitido como herramienta poética la figura utilizada es la metáfora. En este caso el marco común son los mitos y leyendas por lo que su uso será siempre el mismo y su trasfondo será casi siempre el místico puesto que hace parte de la literatura universal y su uso será aceptado en todo texto o conversación que acepte el uso de metáforas. Su interpretación dependerá del conocimiento del receptor con respecto al uso místico de la frase.

Un ejemplo de este tipo de metáforas es el **talón de Aquiles** su significado viene del mito de Troya. Y significa el único punto débil. Su significado es entendido por cualquiera que conozca el mito de Troya.